# html multiple columns unordered list with header

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a unordered list that based on my Style Sheet will either have 1, 2 or 3 columns.
I want to create a heading for the list and it should also respond to the screen size, so if I have 2 column list I should see 2 headings align with the list, or 3 if I have 3 columns.
The list if items will be dynamic so there can be any amount of items listed.
Example
http://jsfiddle.net/francoist/AtX4K/1/

NOTE: the Log No Dimension (heading) in picture below is what I'm trying to add.

Result
[image: Result]

**CSS**

```
    body{
     font-family: "Tahoma";
    }

    ul {
    border-bottom: 1.5px solid #ccc;
    border-top: 1.5px solid #ccc;
    columns: 1;
    -webkit-columns: 1;
    -moz-columns: 1;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

li{
    position: relative;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted #ccc;
    list-style: none;
    list-style-type: none;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
}

ul li a {
    float: right; /* width of icon + whitespace */
    padding: 5px;
    font-size: 14px;
}

labeltotal{
    float: right;
    font-size: 24px;
}

labeldetail{
    font-size: 24px;
}
labeldetailsmall{
    font-size: 14px;
}
@media  (min-width:  480px) {
    ul {
    border-bottom: 1.5px solid #ccc;
    border-top: 1.5px solid #ccc;
    columns: 1;
    -webkit-columns: 1;
    -moz-columns: 1;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    }
}
@media (min-width:  568px) {
    ul {
    border-bottom: 1.5px solid #ccc;
    border-top: 1.5px solid #ccc;
    columns: 2;
    -webkit-columns: 2;
    -moz-columns: 2;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    }
}
@media  (min-width:  768px) {
    ul {
    border-bottom: 1.5px solid #ccc;
    border-top: 1.5px solid #ccc;
    columns: 3;
    -webkit-columns: 3;
    -moz-columns: 3;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<ul>
<li>
<labeldetailsmall>LOG000001 </labeldetailsmall><labeldetail>2,1 x2,3</labeldetail>        
<a href="#" onclick="alert('Hello World')">edit</a>
<a href="#" onclick="alert('Hello World')">delete</a>
</li>
<li>
<labeldetailsmall>LOG000002 </labeldetailsmall><labeldetail>2,1 x 2,3</labeldetail>
<a href="#" onclick="alert('Hello World')">edit</a>
<a href="#" onclick="alert('Hello World')">delete</a>
</li>
<li>
</ul>
```

Comment: what you are asking is *dynamic* in nature,IMHO, this is not possible with HTML , please tag question to `jQuery / javascript`! :)

Comment: I'm not sure that I agree, but will tag as jQuery / javascript sure theirs more then one solution. The dynamic part just means you can have unlimited items across either 1,2 or 3 columns.

Comment: If the content is added manually then this may be possible, but it would involve YOU deciding to utilise 1, 2 or 3 columns. Will you add the content manually? Or will it be done dynamically?

Comment: The content is manually added, but stored in a viewmodel that binds to the <UL>. so I think the topic of manual and dynamic is actually confusing the topic seeing that the style sheet will decide whether its 1,2,3 columns?

Comment: Just for future reference, instead of using @media to determine the columns I'm using column-width. less code and works just the well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not recommend you to use this function, as it is rife with improper programming practices and may not be that efficient.

It works fine on the first page load, but on window resize, it becomes a 'little' hectic.
However, I wanted to challenge myself today and I took it on.

What this function basically does is that it gets the coordinates of all occurrences of a specified HTML tag (`labeldetailsmall` in this case), picks the elements closest to the top and appends a heading to each while removing the previously inserted heading elements.

The CSS is fuzzy and needs improving (for there is some overlapping of elements).

Once again, use this at your own risk... I just wanted to play with code, and ended up with this.

I just hope that you would get an idea of **one way** you could use to achieve what you want.

---

[UPDATED]

**The jQuery:**

```
function addThoseHeadings(elementTagInput, yourHEADING){ 

    var elementTag = $( elementTagInput );

    var allElementsObject = {positions : {}};

    $(elementTag).each(function( index ) {
        var theOffset = $(this).offset();
        allElementsObject.positions[index] = {
            left: theOffset.left,
            top: theOffset.top
        };
    });

    var arr = Object.keys( allElementsObject ).map(function ( key, subkey ) { return allElementsObject[key][subkey]['top']; });
    var minimumOffset = Math.min.apply( null, arr );

    $.each(allElementsObject.positions, function( indexUnwanted, valueOffsets ) {
        if( valueOffsets.top == minimumOffset ){
            var elementToAppendTo = document.elementFromPoint( valueOffsets.left, valueOffsets.top );
            $( elementToAppendTo ).before( '<span class="replaceThese" style="left:'+(valueOffsets.left)+'px;top:'+(valueOffsets.top-35)+'px;">'+yourHEADING+'</span>' );
        }
    });

}

var yourHEADING = "Log No";

addThoseHeadings( "labeldetailsmall", yourHEADING );

$(window).resize(function() {
    $( ".replaceThese" ).remove();
    addThoseHeadings( "labeldetailsmall", yourHEADING );
});
```

---

**The CSS (needs working on):**

```
span {
    display: inline-block;
    position: fixed;
}
```

I hope that this would be of `some` use to someone!

Comment: Hi Thauwa, I'm going to try it and let you know how it goes.

Comment: I did modify your code, but you are on the right track but it does some weird placing.

Comment: Sorry I did not, long day.

Comment: I've done one or two updates, and looking at the demo you can see what I want to accomplish but it does not work on mobile browsers. DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/AtX4K/10/

Comment: Hi Thauwa, this looks like it will do it. look at this http://www.responsinator.com/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fjsfiddle.net%2FTzDaz%2Fembedded%2Fresult%2F

Comment: Thanks allot for your help I appreciate the work, i'm going with this solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Instead of using px(pixels) for size, try using %.

eg:  font-size: 300%;

Note: % value can be increased or decreased as you need.

Comment: Thanks for tip, I will add it, but thats not solving the issue of adding the header?